# window.location.href + timer

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I want to make a link with a page with
" window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com" "
and few second later I want the tab close

I tried this:

> javascript: window.location.href = 'mailto:address@dmail.com' +
>   setTimeOut(function() {
>            window.close();
>        }, 500);

but it doesn't work :(
I'm new so, if u can explain me it will be appreciated :)
Thank you

Comment: please post any `html` you're using. Also, it is `setTimeout` and not `setTimeOut`. `setTimeout` returns the value of the timeout id and you shouldn't be appending that to the `href`.

Comment: @mani Seeing how OP has `javascript:`, I would think that OP is entering this "code" in the address bar, or OP knows *nothing about JS at all*.

Comment: Please post your code to your post, @Yloyy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
<body onload='javascript: setTimeout(function() {window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com"}, 500);'></body>
```

Comment: If I understood him well, OP wants to fire the `mailto:` link and, after 500 ms, **close the window**.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to open the mail and close the window after 500 ms, you probably want this:

`<body onload='javascript: window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com"; setTimeout(function() {window.close()}, 500)'></body>`

Comment: @Yloyy, I accepted your edit, to remove your original email address